# matplotlib plot boolean array as contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to represent a boolean array as a contour.

The following, very simple, code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([
    [False, False, True, True],
    [False, True, True, False],
    [False, True, False, False],
    [False, False, True, False]])
plt.imshow(arr, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
plt.contour(arr, 1, colors='cyan', linewidths=2)
```

draws the cyan contour in the following image.

[image: matplotlib boolean array contour]

**How do I get a contour that follows the pixel boundaries, as illustrated by the dashed-orange contour?**

The solution may use other functions `plt.contour`, but I would like to keep it vectorial and avoid anything that includes rasterized contours.

Comment: contour plots work on cell-centred coordinates, not the nodal positions

Comment: You could process the imshow image to pick out borders.

Comment: @tom: does this mean that `plt.contour` can’t do what I want? Is there another option you would suggest?

Comment: @cphlewis: a vector solution would be much cleaner, but I keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: I'm wondering if this would be a good data display choice, anyway. You'd be  adding resolution (corners) to the data in a way that's more related to your choice of grid than to the data values.